# Accent color in WinRT

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to get the accent color of the user in a WinRT app? Because I want to use it in my app to personalize the app a little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet unfortunately, which is kind of strange since you can tie into the Brushes and things in WP7, but may be they will provide it in the future. More details found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/c13fa638-e4c3-446c-a317-66c2736d6a75). Also, in the future you might do a quick search for something like this to avoid an answer that's just a few sentences long and was found quickly with minimal effort. Good luck with your app! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" />
```

Source: [C# Detect Accent Colour Changes WinRT XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626470/c-sharp-detect-accent-colour-changes-winrt-xaml)