# C# Detect Accent Colour Changes WinRT XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to detect changes in the Application.Resources Resource dictionary, so I can automatically change the Titlebar to the Accent Colour when it updates. All of the XAML controls and elements change automatically, and when setting a solid colour brush to the address of the *DSDFS* brush, its internal value changes.

This is the code I have tried to use to detect the change:

```
public static DependencyProperty accent = DependencyProperty.Register("DictChange", typeof(ResourceDictionary), typeof(Shell), new PropertyMetadata(Application.Current.Resources, new PropertyChangedCallback(accent_PropertyChanged)));

public ResourceDictionary DictChange
{
    get { return (ResourceDictionary)GetValue(accent); }
    set { SetValue(accent, value); }
}

private static void accent_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _app.SetTitlebar();
}
```

I'm assuming its wrong though, or I'm not sure if that is the right thing to do to detect changes. There was a previous iteration where I used `Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush` and tried to detect its property, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? Please help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not be wrong, but it's probably not the best solution available.

In WinRT XAML, we have this new `ThemeResource` that updates the resources automatically. The tricky bit is to find a way to bind the `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar.BackgroundColor` to `SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush`.

In [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833855/231837), I created a `Behavior` that attaches a *custom* `TitleBar` to the page. If you modify the `Background` property to something like this -

```
<local:FullScreenModeTitleBarBehavior Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}" />
```

Now run the [app](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/FullScreenTitleBarRepo/tree/master/FullScreenTitleBarRepo) and you will see the background color gets updated when you change the `accent color` of the system, as shown in the picture below -

[image]

Basically in your case, you just need to create a similar (& simpler?) `Behavior` that acts like a bridge to link the `BackgroundColor` of the `TitleBar` to the `SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush`, via `ThemeResource` binding.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did something similar, how do you respond to the SystemNavigationManager Back Button? Do you have something move on a margin?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming its wrong though, or I'm not sure if that is the right thing to do to detect changes.

You cannot detect the key-value changes in the Resource Dictionary by registering a DependencyProperty because the ResourceDictionay is not an [ObservableCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx). 
[image]

There are no build-in support to detect the key-value changes in a Resource Dictionary.

As a workaround, you can consider create an internal observable collection to detect the changes.